# CSS list dropping down a line from image

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/2h6p3vvd/

I'm trying to align my list to the right of the logo, however it seems to sit on the line below, but still to the right.

HTML

```
<header>
    <nav class="container">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./post" id="recruit">Add</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    padding-top: 65px;
    padding-bottom: 65px;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header nav {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

header ul {
    float: right;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Is this an issue with the `float`, and should I be using some sort of `overflow` rule to correct it?

Comment: Please include the relevant/minimal code in the question too.

Comment: You're supposed to show the code as well as providing a link to JsFiddle. How did you get around it?

Comment: @Lee - He highlighted `float` and `overflow` as code. -1

Comment: Edited - sorry chaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `li` has inherited the `line-height` from `nav` parent... Reset it, and it will be inline:

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2h6p3vvd/3/)

```
header ul li {
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, keep in mind that `float` makes an element float over the element that comes **after** it. So, your `ul` must be put before the logo, so that it can float accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect on my website when I add this. Even when I remove the line-height from the parent it doesnt do anything

Comment: Is it a public website? Can you provide the URL?

Answer (score 0):

The `ul` is applying a top margin, which pushes the list down.

To avoid this, add the following to your `header ul` style:

```
  margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my website either. I should have stated my website has a ```* {margin: 0; padding: 0}``` rule

Comment: @ZachSaucier, even with the float, both Chrome and Firefox apply a top margin to the `ul`.  You can see this by adding/removing the margin style in this fork:  http://jsfiddle.net/hrr5vdaw/4/

Comment: @JamesWillson, setting `margin` and `padding` globally does make my response invalid.  @LcSalazar's response should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Change line height to zero and add float left http://jsfiddle.net/2h6p3vvd/4/
try this

```
header {
padding-top: 65px;
padding-bottom: 65px;
}

.container {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.container img{
position:absolute;
}
header nav {
height: 50px;
line-height: 0px;
}

 header ul {
 margin-left:0px;
float:left; 
}

ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: I dont really want to use negative margin it's a bit of a hack

Answer (score 0):

Write your html structure following way

```
<header>
<nav  class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="" alt="" /></a>
    </div>  
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./post" id="recruit">Add</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
</header>
```

and write css like

```
   .container {
      width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .logo{width: 300px;float:left;}
   .menu{float:left;}
```

Comment: Check here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/168659703/test/index.html . It is working to me . I have wrote above code. @JamesWillson

Answer (score -1):

Better put them in table columns with `border="0px"` and `width=100%` with one extra column in the middle
eg:

```
<header>
<nav class="container">
<table width=100% border=0px>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="index.html"><img src="#"></a></td>
    <td width=100%><!--This column is only needed only when you want to push image and list to extreme left and right respectively--></td>
    <td><ul>
        <li><a href="./post" id="recruit">Add</a></li>
    </ul></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Using a table here isn't appropriate I dont think

Comment: It's against the modern standards to use tables for layout